# Mutt and maildir format

Tags: email, mutt, maildir

I am trying to set up `mutt` to use `maildir` format. I have the following in my `.muttrc` file:

```
set mbox_type=Maildir
set folder="~/.mail/"
set mbox="~/.mail/"
set spoolfile="~/.mail/"
set record="~/.mail/sent"
set postponed="~/.mail/drafts"
```

In my `~/.mail/` folder, I have the subfolders `cur  new  sent  tmp`. So far so good.  But instead of storing the sent mails in `~/.mail/sent/` mutt creates again the subfolder structures `~/.mail/sent/{cur,new,tmp}`. And stores all sent mails in `~/.mail/sent/cur/`. I find this confusing. is there any reason why this is so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you have set

```
set mbox_type=Maildir
```

which configures the default mail-box type for newly created mailboxes to maildir.

And the maildir standard says that a maildir `X` must have sub-folders `{cur,new,tmp}`. A folder `sent` is **not** described by the maildir standard.

Thus, when you specify as destination `~/.mail/sent` mutt interprets it as maildir base path and creates the usual sub-directories `{cur,new,tmp}` there, if they are not already present.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Does it mean that if I want to store sent mail in maildir format (every message in separate file), I must have the directory structure `sent/{cur,new,tmp}` even if I don't need it ?

Comment: @MartinVegter: You *do* need it, because it is *part of the format*. It is not something arbitrary that mutt does. You could try `mh` as a somewhat simpler format. (By the way, the usual convention for Maildir+ subfolders is `~/Mail/.foo.bar.baz` – the "filesystem" layout, `~/Mail/foo/bar/baz`, is less common.)